# How to use same build.gradle files for multiple Android projects (without copying/pasting)

Tags: android, gradle

I want to use the same build.gradle files (project level and application level) for multiple projects. Right now I am accomplishing this by copying and pasting those files from an older project to a newer one. However, I would like to know an easier and less tedious way of going about this, such as perhaps importing gradle files from a certain directory and replacing the default versions.

Comment: Host the `Gradle` files to a Repo and pull them? This way, it's centrally accessed and any other developer can get hold of them. If you were to change it then everyone else gets the change too...?

Answer (score 0):

You have two good options here. You can read about all the options in [Gradle's docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html).

But it boils down to two options, the first is easier but less safe. You can do what @Subby recommended and put them into a repo where you do something like "apply from 'http://raw.github.come/bla/bla/bla'" which will work, but as soon as you loose internet connectivity you will no longer be able to build. This also makes it hard if someone updates your build may just break.

The second is to publish binary artifacts for your org/company where people can use dependency resolution and Gradle's cache to save the artifact locally so you can build offline. This is called `binary plugins`. You can read about it in the docs, or I have a blog post that works through how to do this with something you can work along with [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/gradle-jig-ethan-hall).

Answer (score 0):

If you open the project file you will find a file called build.gradle you can transfer this file to other projects like any other file in your project, and also you can upload it to any drive service like google drive or Dropbox so other developers can use it.